Additional columns not being added when mergeSchema is set to true in Spark Structured Streaming
I have a spark structured streaming job(Kafka). I want to update the table with any additional incoming columns. I have mergeSchema set to true but my columns are not being updated by default.
My initial schema looks like this:
    schema = StructType([
        StructField('id', IntegerType(), False),
        StructField('_last_modified', TimestampType(), False)
    ])
    create_table(schema)

    response = (df
            .writeStream
            .format("delta")
            .option("checkpointLocation",
                    f"{task_data['mount-path']}/{task_data['repo']}/checkpoints/{task_data['table']}")
            .option("mergeSchema", "true")
            .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
            .foreachBatch(batch_processor)
            .outputMode("append")
            .trigger(**trigger_options)
            .start())
    return response

The schema of the incoming event has the following columns:
event_header, health_channel, tag, id, _last_modified
My update statement looks is the following
 (DeltaTable.forName(spark, f"{database}.{table_name}")
 .alias('target')
 .merge(df.alias('updates'), 'target.id = updates.id')
 .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
 .whenMatchedUpdateAll()
 .execute())

When I query the table it only has id and _last_modified
+-----------+--------------------+
|         id|      _last_modified|
+-----------+--------------------+
|-1983128741|2024-06-06 15:37:...|
|-1754765245|2024-06-06 15:37:...|
| -653581293|2024-06-06 15:37:...|
| -395059457|2024-06-06 15:37:...|
|  -41029294|2024-06-06 15:37:...|
|  290622214|2024-06-06 15:37:...|

My understanding is that mergeSchema should be updating the table with the additional fields

please add the sample data you are using.

also check if the columns are present in read stream data df.

Try to add below statement at the top
set spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled = true

